# Fuzzing using Qemu or Unicorn

Tags: embedded, qemu, unicorn, fuzzing, afl-fuzz

I'm studying fuzzing and I need to know when to use qemu mode and when to use unicorn mode if I want to fuzz embedded systems software?

I expect that the difference will based on the application I'm going to fuzz, But I can't realize what is that difference.

Thanks in advance